# 'IndexError: list index out of range' when I used python split to string include Chinese

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

I have a problem when I used split() to a dataframe.
My python is python3.6.
My code is:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':['高 1', '中 2']})
print(data)
data['c'] = [x.split()[2] for x in data['b']]
# data['c'] = list(map(lambda x: x.split()[2], data['b']))
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-1d9b75c9fa9f> in <module>()
      1 data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':['高 1', '中 2']})
      2 print(data)
----> 3 data['c'] = [x.split()[2] for x in data['b']]

<ipython-input-42-1d9b75c9fa9f> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':['高 1', '中 2']})
      2 print(data)
----> 3 data['c'] = [x.split()[2] for x in data['b']]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

and I used `data['c'] = list(map(lambda x: x.split()[2], data['b']))` , I got the same error `IndexError: list index out of range`
How to solve this? I want to get the number, Thanks.

```
###############################################################################
```

Thanks to @U9-Forward. I tried use it for my test and it worked.
But when I used to [kaggle test](https://www.kaggle.com/ruiqurm/lianjia). The floor attribute still return the same error. I can only get the value '高': `df['floor'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])`. I am confused! Is there any reason about codec? I used `pd,read_csv(data,'gbk')`

Comment: Can you also share the value of `x`?

Answer (score 3):

Because python indexing starts from 0, so first element index is 0, second element index is 1, and so on..., so ya have to do:

```
data['c'] = [x.split()[1] for x in data['b']]
```

Also, more pandasic is like:

```
data['c'] = data['b'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[1])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have update my problem, could you please help me out

Comment: @J.LOGAN You're sure? what happens when you copy my code again and then paste it into Kaggle?